# Need help resolving TypeError in Julia

Tags: julia, typeerror

So, I just decided to try to learn Julia, and started by following the [Julia for DataScience lectures on JuliaAcademy](https://juliaacademy.com/courses/). In the first lecture, I get instructed to clone the [DataScience repository on GitHub](https://github.com/JuliaAcademy/DataScience). According to instructions, I activated the environment with `activate` and check the status (`status`). I then ran `instantiate` to update any necessary packages, and get the following error message:

```
    ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected VersionNumber, got Pkg.Types.VersionSpec
    Stacktrace:
     [1] load_urls(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:456
     [2] #download_source#39 at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:632 [inlined]
     [3] download_source at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:631 [inlined]
     [4] instantiate(::Pkg.Types.Context; manifest::Nothing, update_registry::Bool, verbose::Bool, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:820
     [5] instantiate(::Pkg.Types.Context) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:748
     [6] #instantiate#116 at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:744 [inlined]
     [7] instantiate() at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:744
     [8] do_cmd!(::Pkg.REPLMode.Command, ::REPL.LineEditREPL) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/REPLMode/REPLMode.jl:400
     [9] do_cmd(::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::String; do_rethrow::Bool) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/REPLMode/REPLMode.jl:381
     [10] do_cmd at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/REPLMode/REPLMode.jl:376 [inlined]
     [11] (::Pkg.REPLMode.var"#24#27"{REPL.LineEditREPL,REPL.LineEdit.Prompt})(::REPL.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/REPLMode/REPLMode.jl:542
     [12] (::Atom.var"#4#15"{Pkg.REPLMode.var"#24#27"{REPL.LineEditREPL,REPL.LineEdit.Prompt}})(::REPL.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at /home/nord06019185/.julia/packages/Atom/BPtI0/src/Atom.jl:31
     [13] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
     [14] invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:711 [inlined]
     [15] run_interface(::REPL.Terminals.TextTerminal, ::REPL.LineEdit.ModalInterface, ::REPL.LineEdit.MIState) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/REPL/src/LineEdit.jl:2354
     [16] run_frontend(::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::REPL.REPLBackendRef) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/REPL/src/REPL.jl:1055
     [17] run_repl(::REPL.AbstractREPL, ::Any) at /build/julia-98cBbp/julia-1.4.1+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/REPL/src/REPL.jl:206
     [18] (::Base.var"#764#766"{Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool})(::Module) at ./client.jl:383
     [19] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
     [20] invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:711 [inlined]
     [21] run_main_repl(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./client.jl:367
     [22] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:305
     [23] _start() at ./client.jl:484
```

Can anyone help me interpret this error message, and, if possible, help me resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version - [Julia 1.6.1](https://julialang.org/downloads/#current_stable_release)?

Comment: I did after seeing your comment, and that did the trick. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the notebooks have actually have been recently updated for use with Julia 1.6, despite the mention of Julia 1.4 in the readme. In particular, the Project.toml [here](https://github.com/JuliaAcademy/DataScience/blob/08d6cfa52992f2abe2d24dcc2660a2d1c2f56d5a/Project.toml#L56) seems to specifically require Julia 1.6, so that is likely why it was failing on Julia 1.4.

I have also also tested that the Manifest.toml *can* be instantiated in Julia 1.6.1, so I suspect that will likely fix the issue for you as well.

An issue has been opened to potentially clarify this in the documentation https://github.com/JuliaAcademy/DataScience/issues/35

Comment: Thanks for forwarding this issue. I can confirm 1.6.1 fixed the issue for me. For future reference, are `TypeError`s generally linked to version conflicts, or can other issues trigger them as well?

Comment: For this particular case, the part of the error where it says "expected VersionNumber, got Pkg.Types.VersionSpec" provided a bit of a hint because it suggested that something pretty internal wasn't getting the type it expected, perhaps due to one type or the other being deprecated between Julia versions. In general, TypeErrors though just mean that something wasn't the type it was asserted to be - say, try pasting  `1.0::Float64` (correct assertion) vs `1.0::Int64` (should  TypeError) into the REPL.